# Joomla JForm SQL-Field: Get condition from global configuration

Tags: joomla-3.4, jform

i got the following field in my form.xml-definition:

```
<field  name="attachedto" 
        type="sql"  
        label="COM_BESTIA_FIELD_ATTACHEDTO" 
        query="SELECT id, title FROM #__bestia_items WHERE state = 1" 
        key_field="id" 
        value_field="title" 
        multiple="true"
        required="false">
</field>
```

Now I would like to change the `state = 1` according to the settings in the configuration of the component. If config says "use state = 0" the query should change from `WHERE state = 1` to `WHERE state = 0`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

With the SQL form field type which you are using this is not possible. However you could [develop a custom form field type.](https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_custom_form_field_type). Consider subclassing the existing JFormFieldList which will help you a lot. You will only have to write the getOptions() method.

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

jimport('joomla.form.helper');
JFormHelper::loadFieldClass('list');

class JFormFieldAttachedto extends JFormFieldList {

    protected $type = 'Attachedto';

    public function getOptions() 
    {
        // Get component config (JComponentHelper::getParams('com_yourcomponent'));
        // Make SQL query
        // Return all options as array
    }
}
```